# World of Light current completion percentage?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

How do I see my current completion percentage in World of Light in Super Smash Brothers Ultimate?

Answer (score 5):

It shows it to you when choosing a save file during World of Light.

[image]

Comment: I think you may only be able to see the percentage after completing the game for the first time, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: My save file doesn't have completion % so I think Chase is right.